# How to add a title to a table using :before selector?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add "Table" title before all tables using css `:before`.
For some reason the `:before` `content` is behaving as a cell which expands the width of the first column to the width of itself.
How to add a title to a table  using `:before` which should behave as an independent title?

```css
div#myDiv table:before {
  content: "Table";
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
}
div#myDiv table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it `display: table-caption;`

```css
div#myDiv table:before {
  content: "Table";
  display: table-caption;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
}
div#myDiv table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that a child box of a table box must be proper table child. Otherwise, it will generate an anonymous parent according to [Anonymous table objects](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#anonymous-boxes).

In your case, the pseudo-element will be wrapped inside an anonymous `table-cell` box, which will be wrapped inside an anonymous `table-row` box.

Therefore, the content of the pseudo-element will belong only to the first column of the table, and can make it grow.

Instead, if you want that content to be inside the table wrapper box but outside the table box itself, you can use `display: table-caption`. According to [Tables in the visual formatting model](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#model),

> The table generates a principal block box called the
>   *table wrapper box* that contains the table box itself and any caption boxes (in document order). The table box is a block-level box that
>   contains the table's internal table boxes. The caption boxes are
>   block-level boxes that retain their own content, padding, margin, and
>   border areas, and are rendered as normal block boxes inside the table
>   wrapper box.
>
> [image]

```css
#myTable:before {
  content: "Table";
  display: table-caption;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#myTable td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, set the display property of the before content to `table-caption`:

```css
div#myDiv table:before {
  content: "Table";
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  display: table-caption;
}
div#myDiv table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```